# Search Bar textfield cursor color not changing in mac Catalyst it's showing black color ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, search, uisearchbar, searchbar

i also try to change with "searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.tintColor = .white"
but it's not working issue facing after xcode 13 update.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a custom searchController and into the setup to change the tintColor of all the subviews that are different of UIButton .
Here an example :

```
class CustomSearchController: UISearchController {

var placeHolder:String?

private var catalogSearchBar = CatalogSearchBar()
override public var searchBar: UISearchBar {
    get {
        catalogSearchBar.placeholder = placeHolder
        return catalogSearchBar
    }
}
```

}

class CatalogSearchBar: UISearchBar {

```
init() {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setup()
}

private func setup() {
    backgroundColor =  Constants.shared.navigationBar.lightModeBgColor
    
    // text field
    let textField = searchTextField
    textField.subviews.forEach { (view) in
        if ((view as? UIButton) != nil) {
            view.tintColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
    textField.frame.size.height = 35
    self.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 4, vertical: 0)
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    textField.placeholder = self.placeholder
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : "", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
    textField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.25).cgColor
    if let view = textField.value(forKey: "backgroundView") as? UIView {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    textField.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 15)
    textField.textColor = UIColor.white
    textField.tintColor =  UIColor.white
    
    // search icon
    let leftView: UIView = {
        let image = UIImage(named: "search")
        let padding = 8
        let size = 20
        let outerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size + padding, height: size) )
        let iconView  = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: padding, y: 0, width: size, height: size))
        iconView.tintColor = UIColor.white
        iconView.image = image
        outerView.addSubview(iconView)
        return outerView
    }()
    textField.leftView = leftView

}
```

}

Comment: i have try this code and it's working now        
let textInputTraits = searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.value(forKey: "textInputTraits") as? NSObject
        textInputTraits?.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "insertionPointColor")